# Java - Reverse Word Order, Vector

Tags: java, vector

So, the question is to reverse the order of words in a sentence that is to be entered by a user. I've come across a lot of examples in which the words are hardcoded in, and I can reverse those no problem. But when I try to adapt the code for a scanner input, I can't even get the vector to print the input, let alone reverse it. nothing happens..
Here's the code. If someone could help me out, that'd be great!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = null;
      Vector v = new Vector();
      String words;

      System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
      try {
          s = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                words = s.next();
                v.add(words);
            }
        } 
        finally {
               if (s != null) {
                   s.close(); // Close scanner when no more input is available
                }
      }  
      System.out.println(v);
  }
```

PS: I can't even get the vector to show it's input, let alone reverse it.. so I'm still stuck there.
And. It has to be vector because that's what the assignment wants!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Vector` and not `ArrayList`?

Comment: why don't you post that code, and we can help you with it? I really doubt if any reversal logic is present in this code.

Comment: I can't even the vector to show, so I haven't gotten it to reverse yet! And it has to be Vector for the assignment criteria.

Comment: I believe you never exit from the while loop if testing in IDE.

Comment: Is it hanging? without showing Vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your code with a small modification. It is using v.add(0, words) to insert the last word read into the first position. I also changed `Vector` to `Vector<String>`. Use Ctrl+D to exit in unix.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = null;
      Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
      String words;

      System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
      try {
          s = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                words = s.next();
                v.add(0, words);
            }
        } 
        finally {
               if (s != null) {
                   s.close(); // Close scanner when no more input is available
                }
      }  
      System.out.println(v);
  }
```

Example:

```
Enter a sentence: 
aa bb cc
[cc, bb, aa]
```

(Ctrl+D to terminate.)

Comment: that worked beautifully! Thanks. Amazing how adding a 0 can make the difference haha.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested your code, and it works fine (obviously, it doesn't reverse the vector).

The issue is that you need to tell it when you're finished typing the sentence.

On Unix, this is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> at the end of the input. On Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you don't do this, the code just sits there waiting indefinitely for more input.

Comment: Thanks! I see that now. Is there a way to get it to terminate once an enter is pressed?

Comment: @AC: You could call `s.nextLine()` once, and then use `String.split()` on the result.